# Number sequence: 5, 12, 24, 36, 52, 68, 84, 100, ? What's next?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

Replace the question mark and explain the rule behind this sequence:

> 5, 12, 24, 36, 52, 68, 84, 100, ?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A100479

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next term is:

> **120**

Because the terms are all:

> The sum of the next 2 consecutive prime numbers:
>
>  2+3=5,
>  5+7=12,
>  11+13=24,
>  17+19=36,
>  23+29=52,
>  31+37=68,
>  41+43=84,
>  47+53=100

Meaning that the next term must be:

> **59+61=120**

Comment: I *feel* like this question is a duplicate of an existing one, but a quick search before posting did not reveal an appropriate question... Happy to stand corrected if anybody finds one! :)

Comment: Yes, 120 is correct. I think you might refer to my previous post which also consisted of prime numbers. They were similar but not the same.

Comment: @Prim3numbah That may be it - the multiplication one...

Answer (score 0):

119? With regard to the main increase amount (ie 7, 12, 16), change of +5 then 0 repeated x 1, change of +4 then 0 repeated x 3, change of 3 then 0 repeated x 5. With the zero repetition being increasing odd numbers and the main increasing amount reducing by 1 each round.

Comment: I see. But no, its not correct.